# Android - Appcelerator : Add n elements simultaneously

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator

```
Titanium SDK 5.5.1.G.A
```

I'm converting an iOS app to be compatible with Android.

On iOS if i do this :

```
var v1 = Ti.UI.createView({
    width : 10,
    height : 10,
    opacity : 0
});
var v2 = Ti.UI.createView({
    width : 10,
    height : 10,
    opacity : 0
});

window.add(v1,v2);
```

The 2 view are added correctly. But on Android only the first view. It's a bug or the normal behavior on this platform?

For Android i have to do this :

```
window.add(v1);
window.add(v2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On iOS Ti.UI.View.add() accepts an array of views:
https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/blob/0357b4796abf0032485018fac42614a94f826c9b/iphone/Classes/TiViewProxy.m#L149

On Android it does not:
https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/blob/master/android/titanium/src/java/org/appcelerator/titanium/view/TiUIView.java#L181

Related question on Q&A:
https://community.appcelerator.com/topic/3075/unable-to-add-array-of-views-to-parent-view-on-android

AFAIK Developer Team are going to add array support for Android in v 6.1.0 of Titanium SDK.

Comment: I noticed that in docs it already said that array is possible: http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.View-method-add

Comment: Actually an array on 2 label added to a view crash the app (on Android with SDK 5.5.1GA)

Comment: yeah. I found related ticket: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-19482

so I was right:  fix version is 6.1.0 :(